# Package for TLD algorithm in indigo

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found TLD algorithm package in github but it is for groovy. is there any indigo package for TLD algorithm or any similar object tracking algorithm ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215478/package-for-tld-algorithm-in-indigo/) by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 173 on 2015-08-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[My version of TLD for ROS](https://github.com/MalcolmMielle/ros_open_tld) <- I know it's written that I used it under groovy but it's catkinized and from what I remember it should work without problem under indigo.

[My version used to do simple 3D Tracking thank to TLD](https://github.com/MalcolmMielle/ros_open_tld_3d) <- I used this version under indigo. If you want to remove the PCL dependency it's pretty easy to do so. Without suppressing the PCL dependices, you can use the 2D version of the tracker by itself by changing the parameter *Tracking3D* to **false**.

[Another Version of TLD for ROS by Ronan](https://github.com/Ronan0912/ros_opentld) <- Can't talk for him but it's catkinized so it should work on indigo (?)

---

Originally posted by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) with karma: 1172 on 2015-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on 2015-08-10**:
I have added an issue in github for your package over [here](https://github.com/MalcolmMielle/ros_open_tld/issues), please look into it and clarify.

**Comment by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on 2015-08-12**:
I tried to execute your latest 3d package for TLD as per your advice and faced some issues, i posted that [here](https://github.com/MalcolmMielle/ros_open_tld_3d/issues/1) please clarify